# Restrict pagination using entity field query

Tags: 7, database

I have pagination using entity field query:

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node');
$query->entityCondition('bundle', 'content_type');
$query->pager(3,0);
$result = $query->execute();
$pager=theme('pager');
print render ($pager);
```

and it is successfully displayed like below,

[image]

I need to restrict them to display to number 6 then ... like below
:
`1,2,3,4,5,6....next,last`

Answer (score 1):

It's very easy. Just use

```
$pager=theme('pager', array('quantity' => 6));
```

Comment: Thanku @Eugene if I want to remove first and last tabs. Need only previous and next links.Should I implement `theme_pager_last()` manage in entity field query?

Comment: I think that you should redefine theme_pager in your theme and remove first and last links from this function